# App crashes when back button press while picking Image

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

My flutter app crashes when  pressing of back button while picking an image.How can I solve that?

Here is Image picking part

```
 _openGallery(BuildContext context) async{

  var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);



  this.setState((){
    imageFile = picture;
  });

  if (picture==null) {
     Navigator.of(context).pop();
  } else{
    final File newImage = await imageFile.copy('$_localPath/name.jpg');
  }



  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error logs? I'm guessing its because you're returning a null value from your ImagePicker. Add an if statement where it skips to `Navigator.pop...` if picture is `null`

Comment: I added if statement and `Navigator.of(context).pop();` but It not returning to main screen.It gave me a black screen.Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I meant after your `var picture`, add an if statement, end it just before `Navigator.of`

Comment: @Axen_Rangs Use named routes if you see black screen or pushreplacement

Comment: @Sidak I've edited the question can you please check whether it's correct..

Comment: You dont need the `Navigator.pop` in the last line if you're already popping it if null